# How to "Allow service to interact with desktop" for a web service?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, windows-services

I'm trying to run some applications through a web service that I wrote. I've given necessary user permissions, but I still cannot see any user interface of the started applications, even though I know that they are running because they are listed in Task Manager.

When I looked into this issue I came up with one solution which is: enabling the "Allow service to interact with desktop" checkbox. But when I looked for my service in Services I could not find it running there. I don't even know what my service's name is: could anyone help me with this?

Does my web service turn into a windows service while it is running?
If it doesn't how can I find it?

Comment: Given that even *real* services are being [increasingly steered away from this option](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc756339(WS.10).aspx), trying to find a way to turn it on for something else is a bit of a dead-end. The whole approach seems questionable - why are you trying to run interactive applications on the server?

Comment: I am working on a project that is a multiplayer game automation system. It is going to be a system controlled over a web site. I need start the games on the server, that's why. So you think it is an impossible thing to accomplish??

Answer (score 0):

Your web service is not a "Service" which will appear in Services - those are [Windows Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685967%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)... very different concept.

You can't have a web service "interacting with the desktop" on the server unless the service host process has access to the interactive user's [Window Station](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687096%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This is impossible with an ASP.NET web service, which is hosted by IIS and will be running in a separate session with a non-interactive Window Station.

If you instead implement the web service using WCF, hosting it in an application run by a logged in interactive user, you might get round the security obstacles which prevent the started applications showing a visible UI.

However, I don't know what you mean by "a system controlled over a web site": that sounds like the kind of thing which needs IIS and shouldn't be run by an interactive user - so you may run into other problems. If you explain in more detail what you are trying to do there are probably better solution architectures we could suggest.

Comment: thanks for your concern. What I meant saying "a system controlled over a web site" is ; I have a server computer, and I want to use it as a dedicated game server machine. Which I will do with the website is I will let admins to start or close the games over the web site. I was trying to ASP.NET web service attached to the website but as you said it wasn't working as I expected. That's it, now by your suggestion I will look into WCF and try to implement with it. If you think there exist a better way of doing that I will be happy and grateful to hear it.